# Vba Sumifs Array Values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sumifs

I got an Array with double values. Now I want to sum all values if sheet, date, and name are the same. I think I will need another array for the results?

My values array looks like:

```
Sheet     Date     Value  Name   
Sheet1    04.13    4,2    Friedrich
Sheet1    04.13    13     Karl
Sheet1    04.13    5      Friedrich
Sheet1    05.15    8      Mark
```

My result array should be:

```
Sheet     Date     Value  Name
Sheet1    04.13    9,2    Friedrich
Sheet1    04.13    13     Karl
Sheet1    05.15    8      Mark
```

But i dont know how to build it.

Heres my Code for the Values Array.

```
Dim values(160, 3) As Variant
For temp5 = 1 To lastrow

    values(temp5 - 1, 0) = blatt.Name
    values(temp5 - 1, 1) = Format(blatt.Cells(temp5 + 1, 2).Value, "mm.yy")
    If (IsEmpty(blatt.Cells(temp5 + 1, 4).Value)) Then
        values(temp5 - 1, 2) = 0
    Else
        values(temp5 - 1, 2) = blatt.Cells(temp5 + 1, 4).Value
    End If
    values(temp5 - 1, 3) = blatt.Cells(temp5 + 1, 8).Value

Next
```

Comment: Call me an old fuddy duddy, but I'd try to take the easy way out with `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct( ... )` or if you want the result in a cell, `Workbook.Worksheet.Range.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT( ..."`

Comment: Could be a nice idea. Will try that